# syscall OSX create file [open]

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I intend to create a file using Mac system calls (OS X and not the bios for now). Everything compiles well, but the result that should be the creating the file **"fileName db "Teste.txt", 0xA, 0x0"** is not realized and I do not understand. can you help me, I also post you the source code compiled with nasm
Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
 

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; TITLE: SOURCE.ASM
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

bits 64

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Definition des syscall
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%define _stdout         0x1
%define _stderr         0x2

%define O_RDONLY        0x0000          ; open for reading only
%define O_WRONLY        0x0001          ; open for writing only
%define O_RDWR          0x0002          ; open for reading and writing
%define O_ACCMODE       0x0003          ; mask for above modes
%define O_CREAT         0x0200          ; create if nonexistant 
%define O_TRUNC         0x0400          ; truncate to zero length 
%define O_EXCL          0x0800          ; error if already exists

%define syscall_write   0x2000004
%define syscall_exit    0x2000001
%define syscall_open    0x2000005
%define syscall_close   0x2000006

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Section code
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
section .text

global start

start:

    xor rax, rax
    xor rbx, rbx
    mov rbx, fileName
    push mode_f
    push FLAGS
    push rbx
    syscall
    pop rax

    xor rbx, rbx
    mov rbx, rax
    mov rax, syscall_exit
    mov rdi, rbx
    syscall


f_open_file:
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbp
    xor rax, rax
    mov rax, syscall_open
    mov rdi, [rbp+8]
    mov rsi, [rbp+16]
    mov rdx, [rbp+24]
    syscall
    pop rax

    if: cmp rax, -1
        jge else
        mov rbx, rax
        mov rax, syscall_close
        mov rdi, rbx
        syscall
        pop rax
        ret
    else:
        xor rbx, rbx
        mov rbx, MsgErrr
        push size_err
        push rbx
        call f_print_data
        xor rax, rax
        mov rax, -1
        ret

f_print_data:
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbp
    mov rax, syscall_write
    mov rdi, _stdout
    mov rsi, [rbp+8]
    mov rdx, [rbp+16]
    syscall
    xor rax, rax
    ret


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Section Data
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

section .data
    fileName    db "Teste.txt", 0xA, 0x0
    MsgErrr     db "Erreur open File", 0xA, 0x0
    size_file   equ ($-fileName)
    size_err    equ ($-MsgErrr)
    mode_f      equ 0777
    FLAGS       equ 0xA02 ;( O_RDWR| O_CREAT| O_EXCL )
```

Comment: What's the error code? Have you tried to use a syscall tracer?

Comment: I have no error code that appears when I compile: 
nasm -f macho64 c_file.asm -o file.o && ld file.o -o File  && ./File

I used the solution of @Sep Roland the result is remains the same. In the current directory there is no file created, I confess that I am a lost; Maybe the "f_open_file" function I wrote is totally wrong?

Comment: See the edit on answer. You didn't setup `RAX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> fileName    db "Teste.txt", 0xA, 0x0
> ```

The inclusion of the newline code `0xA` is fine for displaying purposes, but for opening it is no good! Drop it:

```
fileName    db "Teste.txt", 0x0
```

---

> ```
> mov rbx, fileName
> push mode_f
> push FLAGS
> push rbx
> syscall
> ```

Your code is missing the *open* command in order to create the file!

```
mov rbx, fileName
push mode_f
push FLAGS
push rbx
mov  rax, syscall_open
syscall
```

---

> ```
> f_open_file:
>     mov rbp, rsp
>     push rbp
> ```

To actually preserve `rbp` you need to swap these two instruction:

```
f_open_file:
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp
```

In doing so, you'll also need to adjust the offsets used on `[rbp + ...]`.

---

All of your subroutines forget to `pop rbp`, and so you end up with an unbalanced stack. This leads to "segmentation faults".

Comment: Thank you indeed, I missed the call of my function and there of course, I see errors appear despite the file was created it must be the return code that I exploit very badly.

->Erreur open File
->Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: How could you exploit the return code? Your program never reaches *f_open_file* because there's a *syscall_exit* just above it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write assembly code that makes direct system calls, use a Linux virtual machine.

The macOS system call interface is *not* a public API. There is no official documentation for this interface, and it differs in a number of important ways from the Linux system call interface. This makes it a terrible place for a beginner to be learning assembly!

There are much better debugging tools available on Linux as well, such as `strace`, which will allow you to see the exact system calls being made by your application.

Comment: it exist the ABI documentation for Mac OS X that is available but I admit it's not obvious for a beginner https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html[/link]

Comment: @sambia39 The system call interface is (partially) documented, but the system calls themselves are not. Note that the system calls often do not have the same interface as the libc wrappers.

Comment: The FreebSD documentation applies to MacOS for both the 32-bit and 64-bit System Call interface. There is only one catch and that is on MacOS the 64-bit system calls have to have 0x2000000 added to them compared to their FreeBSD counterparts. The system call interface is public, you just need to know where to look.There is a header file that comes with each OSX that lists them as well.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Finally, I think I find my mistakes. The first is the conditional jump instead of `jge` it would be rather `jnle`. And the other difficulty I experience is to go up the return code of the open function in `start` to perform a `exit(1);` somewhat like `return EXIT_FAILLURE`. To say that the program, it is to arrest with a code error -1 instead of the error message: segmentation fault: 11

Comment: You can't return from `start`. (This isn't even specific to macOS.) Normally, the runtime calls `main` from `start`, then calls `_exit` with the return code after running at-exit handlers.

Comment: have you checked /usr/include/sys/syscall.h?